# MediaQuery insets return zero

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to detect the height of the keyboard by using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` but for some reason, it works when the call is made from within the same code block as a `Scaffold` but, not when I call it from within a `StatefulWidget`'s build method further down the widget tree.

I don't really understand why this is happening as as far as I understand, the `MediaQuery` is a property of `MaterialApp` of which there is only a single instance.

For example this works fine:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     // more widgets here
      Text('${MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom}'),
     // more widgets here
  }
```

However, calling from within a method of the state of a stateful widget placed into the scaffold does not:

```dart
void checkInset() {
    print(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom);
}
```

It always returns 0.

Can someone push me in the right direction here? I think i'm probably missing something to do with how `MediaQuery.of` works.

Answer (score 1):

This was a really annoying bug but I figured it out eventually. You have to add the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` parameter to the `Scaffold` and then it works properly.

Hope this helps someone avoid the same problem.